# Not able to write a iterator for a Linked List created in python

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

Have tried to create a python Single Linked list , but i'm not able to create a iterator.
Here is my code :

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head=self
        self._tail=self
        self._size=0                    

    def __iter__(self):
        print 'Calling Iterator\n\n'
        _ListIterator(self._head)

class ListObj:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self._data=value
        self._pointingTo=None

class _ListIterator:
    def __init__(self,listHead):
        LIST=None
        self._curNode=listHead
        print dir(self._curNode)

    def __next__(self):
        if self._curNode._pointingTo is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item=self._curNode._data
            self._curNode=self._curNode._pointingTo
            return item
```

This iterator is failing by throwing an error as

```
TypeError: __iter__ returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Do you really have to post the entire code? Please read http://www.sscce.org/ Also, please show your entire traceback.

Comment: Ok , I got that i am passing just a single LinkedList object in the iterator , but how can  i pass the complete list as a whole !

Comment: This is the entire traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __iter__ returned non-iterator of type 'NoneType'

Comment: There is no reason to make the `ListIterator` object. Read the duplicate question and try that.

Comment: Yes , the linked helped,there is no point in making it a seperate object!
Thanks  Lego Stormtroopr

Comment: FWIW: https://gist.github.com/therealprologic/a745f94c2ca2dd8bdba1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_ListIterator(self._head)
```

You forgot to `return` this.

Comment: Thanks , got all possibilities of  making it work  with/without seprate iterator object :)